# Were the lyrics in Coldplay's "Viva la Vida" changed?

Tags: lyrics, history, pop

Did the group Coldplay really originally have the words *"Roman Catholic priests are singing"* in their song "Viva la Vida", and later replace it with *"Roman Cavalry choirs are singing"*?

Comment: Where did you find a reference to the version "Roman Catholic **priests** are singing"?

Comment: my personal recollection. that's how I initially heard it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a classic example of a misheard lyric (sometimes known as a ["mongdegreen"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mondegreen)). If you read the lyrics on Coldplay's own [website](http://www.coldplay.com/song/viva-la-vida/) and compare it with the [original song](https://youtu.be/dvgZkm1xWPE) you can hear the original text is "Roman cavalry choirs are singing". This is a fairly obscure reference (made a bit clearer by the reference to missionaries two lines later) and it's easy to understand why a lot of people mishear this as "Roman Catholic choirs are singing".

For a similar discussion see [this question](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/2715/are-the-lyrics-in-teardrop-by-massive-attack-feathers-or-fearless).

Comment: thank you for the answer. I'm aware of the official lyrics *now*. can we be sure though? websites can be changed. youTube songs can be re-uploaded. if it was a 1990s song, I'd asked whether you have an original CD... I would like to be as sure as possible. :)

Comment: actually, now I think this is exactly what it was - I just misheard. thanks for the links!